# Why is my 480p Handbrake conversion of NTSC home video DVD much larger file size than the DVD?

Tags: dvd, handbrake, vhs

I'm not super experienced with video production but I understand the technical basics of resolutions, frame rates, compression types, etc.

I have an NTSC DVD containing a long (3h) home movie shot on VHS.  (A commercial outfit converted the original VHS tape to DVD many years ago.)  I'm trying to produce a digital video file for YouTube, PC viewing, etc.

I used Handbrake to convert it using the "fast 480p" setting that uses h.264 - the original video is pretty low quality to begin with.  But the converted video is over 5GB, larger than the 3GB size of the original DVD .iso image!

The only thing i can think of is that the converted NTSC video has tracking noise along the bottom edge, which might screw up compression, but can someone help me understand how converting a 480p NTSC DVD video results in a LARGER file size?  Should I be using a different compressor or something?

Comment: Try using a highe/slower compression rate, two pass compression, and or VBR below 10 Mb/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast conversion does not do much compression if you select slowest setting it will produce much smaller file size. Or you could swap from H.264 code to H.265, it will reduce your file size dramatically.

Comment: I don't know if  DVD supports h.265. It's pretty new for hardware support.